# Check a specific Value that returned from eloquent in Laravel 8

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

**In my Laravel Controller, I have the following code:**

```
public function test($id)
{
    $emp_check = logentry::where([
        ['EmployeeFK', '=', $id],
        ['DateTime', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(8)]
    ])->latest()->get();
    return $emp_check;
}
```

**and these is the returning from database**

```
{
"LogID": 2,
"DateTime": "2021-09-28 08:16:44",
"LocationX": null,
"LocationY": null,
"EmployeeFK": 1,
"Status": "checked out",
"ErrorResponse": null,
"SalaryChingValue": null,
"SalaryNote": null,
"LogNote": null,
"created_at": "2021-09-28 11:16:44"
}
```

**is there any way to check the "status" value that returned from the eloquent result ?** 
I know there's a some specific way to do that but I really don't know how to write it.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the lists of `status` from the collection?

Comment: i want to check the value of the status in these JSON that retrieved from eloquent

Comment: Since, there might be more than one, you wish to check for individual or in a bulk?

Comment: I wanna to check an individual value

Comment: what type of "Status" in your table?

Comment: What do you need to check status against?

Comment: status is a string value , and I wanna to check if it's (checked in) or (checked out)

Comment: @Mohammed_Alkhatib so what problem use `->where('Status', 'checked in')` to get only checked in statuses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `get()` method to find the result. The `get()` method will return an array of records that you can loop over. You are using id in **where condition** so if you always get a single record you can use:

```
if($emp_check[0]->Status == 'your status'){
    //do something
}
```

It's better to use `first()` to get single record.
or you can use `foreach loop`

```
if($emp_check){
    foreach($emp_check as $v){
        if($v->Status == 'your status'){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following before you return it:

```
if($emp_check['Status'] == 'your condition'){
   //do something
}
```

Not sure if that's what you need, if not, please update your question.

Comment: Unfortunately these answer not gonna work , because the type of returned data is actually a model of employee

Answer (score 0):

maybe i misunderstood, but try

```
$emp_check = logentry::where('EmployeeFK', $id)
    ->where('DateTime', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(8))
    ->where('Status', $status)
    ->latest()->get();
```

Or for one of statuses change to

```
$emp_check = logentry::where('EmployeeFK', $id)
    ->where('DateTime', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(8))
    ->whereIn('Status', $statuses)
    ->latest()->get();
```